# Passing a data class as a variable to a function

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a reusable module for API calls in C#. I want to use this for several different APIs. But I am having trouble passing my data classes dynamically as a variable to my function that handles the API calls.

So let's say, for example, that I am calling two completely different APIs, we'll call them "Api #1" and "Api #2". And I have the following classes:

```
// This is the format of the response from Api #1 GET
public class Api01Get
{
    public int orderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }
}

// This is the format of the response from Api #2 GET
public class Api02Get
{
    public bool isGreen { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the call to my function. It works fine if I use one of my data classes directly like this:

```
var result = CallAPI<Api02Get>(baseAddress, requestUri);
```

But that doesn't allow me the flexibility I am after.

Here is the definition of my function (I have left out other parameters here that do not affect things):

```
private async Task<TResult> CallAPI<TResult>(Uri baseAddress, string requestUri)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
    {
        client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)   
        {
            TResult result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResult>();
        }
    }

    // do other stuff...

    return result;
}
```

Now this is where I am hung up. I must be thinking about this in an incorrect way, but what I am trying to do is something like this for example:

```
object apiModel;

switch (whichAPI)
{
    case "API_01_GET":
        apiModel = new Api01Get();
        break;

    case "API_02_GET":
        apiModel = new Api02Get();
        break;

    // Other cases...

    default:
        break;
}    

var result = CallAPI<apiModel>(baseAddress, requestUri);
```

I get an error when attempting the last line. "The type or namespace name 'apiModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I have tried other things, but this is the version that seemed to get me the closest so this is what I posted.

So I am unsure how to accomplish this or maybe there is a better way altogether. I appreciate any feedback and would be happy to clarify if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't going to help your design problem, but the reason you're getting that error is because `apiModel` isn't a type, it's an object.  Try `apiModel.GetType()`.  (I'm not 100% sure that will work)

Comment: If you could get this to compile and work as written, what would happen next? You still don't know at compile time the type of object to which the `result` variable points, so you could not do anything meaningful with it.

Comment: @MikeH Thank you, I did end up declaring `Type apiModel` instead of `object apiModel`. And `apiModel.GetType()` didn't give me what I wanted.

Comment: @Jay Thanks. I think I understand your point. By following TyCobb's answer below, I would still be able to do something like this afterwards if I wanted: `var value = ((dynamic)result).isGreen;`. However, in order to know that `isGreen` is available, I'd have to know that my Type was `Api02Get`. Are you saying there is no way to determine the Type for this kind of usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use generics here without some extra reflection to dynamically invoke `CallAPI<T>`.

Luckily, [HttpContentExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834253%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) has extra overloads that will allows you to pass in the `Type`. You just need to overload your method and make a minor tweak to `ReadAsAsync`.

```
private async Task<object> CallAPI(Uri baseAddress, string requestUri, Type apiType)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
    {
        ....

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)   
        {
            object result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync(apiType);
        }
    }

    ....

    return result;
}
```

You may still need to change up some of your code prior to this though since you are stuck with `object`.